# Using struct type with function

Tags: c++

Main.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"
SolveSE(1, 2, 3);
```

Header.h

```
struct Solution;
Solution SolveSE(double ax, double bx, double c);
```

SSE.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"
struct Solution
{
    size_t count;
    double *roots;
};

Solution SolveSE(double ax, double bx, double c) 
{   
    if (fabs(ax)<1e-5)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("a should not be a zero");
    }
    double Discriminant = bx - 4 * ax * c;

    if (Discriminant > 0)
    {
        double x1 = -bx + sqrt(Discriminant) / 2 * ax;
        double x2 = -bx - sqrt(Discriminant) / 2 * ax;
        double roots[] = { x1, x2 };
        return { 2, roots };
    }
    if (Discriminant == 0)
    {
        double x1 = -bx + sqrt(Discriminant) / 2 * ax;
        double roots[] = { x1};
        return { 1, roots };
    }
    if (Discriminant < 0)
    {
        return { 0};
    }
    return {};
}
```

Error from Visual Studio:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2027   use of undefined type 'Solution'    SolveSquareEquation c:\users\dima\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\solvesquareequation\solvesquareequation\main.cpp    8

And floating tip say, that return type 'Solution' is incompleate.

There someothing with my function implementation?

test.cpp

```
TEST_METHOD(TestSSE)
{
    Assert::AreEqual<Solution>(SolveSE(1,3,-4), {2, {4, 1}})
}
```

Comment: `struct Solution` definition is only visible in `SSE.cpp`, you should move it to header.

Comment: Please show real code, if you want real answers, instead of obviously fake code.

Comment: I have struct Solution; in Header.h

Comment: Its my real code. I start learning c++.

Comment: You have only forward declaration of struct there. But you need definition `struct Solution { size_t count;  double *roots;};`. Otherwise `Solution` type will be incomplete and cause errors when function is invoked in translation units other than `SSE.cpp`. PS you are also missing some includes, for example `cstdint` for `size_t` and `cmath` for `sqrt`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Do you have any particular complaints about this code? It has some flaws but it is definitely not "obviously fake".

Comment: Yes, the shown code fails to meet the requirements for a [mcve] as explained by stackoverflow.com's [help], that all code samples must comply with.

Comment: You need a function named "[main](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Statements/Functions#main)" in the main.cpp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should move struct to header file:

```
struct Solution
{
    size_t count;
    double *roots;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but how i can get work Assert::AreEqual function with my type "Solution" or what i can do in this case?

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0304 no instance of overloaded function "Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::Assert::AreEqual" matches the argument list SolveQuadraticEquationUnitTest c:\Users\Dima\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SolveSquareEquation\SolveQuadraticEquationUnitTest\unittest1.cpp 35

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2664 'void Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::Assert::AreEqual<Solution>(const T &,const T &,const wchar_t *,const Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::__LineInfo *)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'initializer list' to 'const Solution &' SolveQuadraticEquationUnitTest c:\users\dima\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\solvesquareequation\solvequadraticequationunittest\unittest1.cpp 35

Comment: Any explanations about it?